# Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError error while uploading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, imagemagick, paperclip, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to crop images using Jcrop, I am sending cropping parameters while uploading the image. My model code looks like this

```
has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "500x500>", thumb: "100x100>", large: "700x700>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png", :processors => [:cropper]
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  after_create :reprocess_image, if: :cropping?

  def cropping?
    !crop_x.blank? && !crop_y.blank? && !crop_w.blank? && !crop_h.blank?
  end

  def avatar_geometry(style = :original)
    @geometry ||= {}
    @geometry[style] ||= Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(image.path(style))
  end

  private

  def reprocess_image
    ratio = avatar_geometry.width.to_f / avatar_geometry(:large).width.to_f
    self.crop_x = (crop_x * ratio).round
    self.crop_y = (crop_y * ratio).round
    self.crop_w = (crop_w * ratio).round
    self.crop_h = (crop_h * ratio).round

    image.assign(image)
    image.save
  end
```

But I am getting the following `paperclip` error in `Paperclip::Geometry.from_file(image.path(style))` line,

```
Command :: PATH=/usr/local/bin/:$PATH; identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/home/rajdeepb/projects/ror/demo/Tettares_ROR/public/system/event_attachements/images/000/000/017/original/5993_604345376383295_8200271052700075298_n.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError: Paperclip::Errors::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError
from /home/rajdeepb/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@tror/gems/paperclip-4.3.5/lib/paperclip/geometry_detector_factory.rb:10:in `make'
```

I have tried various solutions already posted on StackOverflow but nothing worked.

I am using following version of Paperclip and dependency gems.

```
paperclip (4.3.5)
  activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
  activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
  cocaine (~> 0.5.5)
  mime-types
  mimemagic (= 0.3.0)
```

I have followed [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images) railscasts session to implement this.

Please help, any clue would be highly appreaciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like Paperclip can't find the `identify` utility that ships with ImageMagick. Is ImageMagick installed? Do you need to updated your environment `PATH` or `MAGICK_HOME` variables? Or perhaps `Paperclip.options[:command_path]`?